# How to horizontal & vertical center images in slick gallery (+fancybox)

Tags: javascript, css, gallery, slick.js

I have much problem with Slick Gallery.
I want to center img - images have different sizes and slick not working well.

Please look at the pictures - this is what I need:
[sketch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv9jk.jpg)

1. when image is small must be on middle
2. when image have big height we centered it in vertical
3. when image have big width we centered it in horizontal

Please look at this code:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $(".slider").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    accessibility: true,
    autoplay: true,
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0px',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    });
});
```

```css
.slider{
    width:440px;
    height:400px;
    background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <a href="/" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="https://naturecanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/boy-in-field.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="http://ca.france.fr/sites/default/files/imagecache/ATF_Image_bandeau_v2/la_france_cote_nature_6.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/beautiful-nature-at-morning-in-misty-spring-forest-with-sun-picture-id506856658?k=6&m=506856658&s=612x612&w=0&h=GWvZGpApXiPXu2AtRX8YZe75-DkZIf6HVqHJuAKCTHk=" /></a>
  <a href="/" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/nature-design-with-bokeh-effect_1048-1882.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a3/3f/86/a33f86fcd8edba60c037318f43346c6d.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/" data-fancybox="images" ><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/687354253371772928/v9LlvG5N.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

How can I center images in slick gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="helper"></span>
<a href="/" data-fancybox="images" >
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/687354253371772928/v9LlvG5N.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Adjust your css like this:

```
.slider{
  width:440px;
  height:400px;
  background: gold;
}
.slider img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
}
.slider {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: but what with center top bottom?

Comment: Check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Comment: I added a new snippet that shows an example of how to center the image vertically.

Answer (score 0):

instead of img use div and background image in css to show image. use `background-size: contain` to have that effect.